# Validate Date strict to format - more than 4 character for year - pySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, to-timestamp

I am trying to validate date received in file against configured date format(using to_timestamp /to_date).

```
schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("date",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("active", StringType(), True)
    ])

input_data = [
    ("27/10/00",'Y'),
    ("27/10/01",'Y'),
    ("27/10/1",'Y'),
    ("27/10/16",'Y'),
    ("27/10",'Y'),
    ("27/10/99",'Y'),
    ("27/10/100",'Y'),
    ("27/10/992",'Y'),
    ("27/10/2000",'Y'),
    ("27/10/9999",'Y'),
    ("27/10/20015",'Y'), ]
date_format = "dd/MM/yyyy"

temp_df = spark.createDataFrame(data=input_data,schema=schema)

df = temp_df.select('*', 
                f.when(f.date_format(f.to_timestamp(f.col('date'), date_format), date_format).isNotNull(), True).otherwise(False).alias('Date_validation'),
                f.date_format(f.to_timestamp(f.col('date'), date_format), date_format).alias('converted_date'),
                )
df.show(truncate=False)
```

my expectation is the code should return False since YYYY is a four character date but the code returns True and prints the converted year as valid one.

[image]

is there anyway I could to a strict validation on date ?

note : formats are configured by user which will be dynamic.

tried to_timestamp and to_date both are having same output

Comment: Hm what version of Spark you're using? It returns False to me as expected

Comment: my bad, have update the code with correct test data.

tried in spark version : 2.4.7 and 3.1.1

Comment: Additionally, we have a requirement to differentiate between YY(strictly 2 digit year) and YYYY(strictly 4 digit year).
in above example if I tried with format "dd/MM/yy" everything except line 5 returns as True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug since 2.4 and had been fixed from 3.0 forward. More information [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/sql-migration-guide.html). In short, there is a configuration called `spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy` with 3 possible values:

- `LEGACY`: Perform like 2.4 where you see the bug
- `EXCEPTION`: Raise exceptions when has an invalid format
- `CORRECTED`: Fix and return your expected result

This is the result with `CORRECTED`:

```py
+-----------+------+---------------+--------------+
|date       |active|Date_validation|converted_date|
+-----------+------+---------------+--------------+
|27/10/00   |Y     |false          |null          |
|27/10/01   |Y     |false          |null          |
|27/10/1    |Y     |false          |null          |
|27/10/16   |Y     |false          |null          |
|27/10      |Y     |false          |null          |
|27/10/99   |Y     |false          |null          |
|27/10/100  |Y     |false          |null          |
|27/10/992  |Y     |false          |null          |
|27/10/2000 |Y     |true           |27/10/2000    |
|27/10/9999 |Y     |true           |27/10/9999    |
|27/10/20015|Y     |false          |null          |
+-----------+------+---------------+--------------+
```

Comment: it work a treat, Thanks!

Comment: Issue with spark 3. I am not able to handle        
date_format = "'day' EEEEE, 'date' MM/dd/yyyy, 'Time' HH:mm:ss"         input_data = [("day Tuesday, date 10/27/1992, Time 23:59:59",'Y'),]

Symbols of ‘E’, ‘F’, ‘q’ and ‘Q’ can only be used for datetime formatting, e.g. date_format. They are not allowed used for datetime parsing, e.g. to_timestamp.